# cumsum within repeating sequence

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
df <- data.frame((v1=c(4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3),v2=c(0,7,3,6,2,6,9,2,4,7,1,4))
```

How do I get the cumsum for v2 as long as v1 is increasing and when v1 is decreasing (dropping from 6 to 1) the cumsum should restart. (Imagine the sequence in v1 goes multiple times from 1 to 6 but could start and end at any number of the sequence) 
The result should look like this:

```
df <- data.frame((v1=c(4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3),v2=c(0,7,3,6,2,6,9,2,4,7,1,4), expected=c(0,7,10,6,8,14,23,25,29,7,8,12)
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can create a group based on the `diff`erence between adjacent elements of 'v1' and then do the `cumsum`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by(grp = cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(v1) < 0))) %>% 
   mutate(new = cumsum(v2)) %>%
   ungroup %>%
   select(-grp)
```

---

Or it can be done in `base R`

```
df$new <- with(df, ave(v2, cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(v1) < 0)), FUN = cumsum))
df$new
#[1]  0  7 10  6  8 14 23 25 29  7  8 12
```